# Possible d3 Bug: dragend fires without any drag event

Tags: d3.js, dom, svg, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I am using d3js drag behavior. here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/epMdE/2/). When I click on element the 'drag' and 'dragend' event fired. Even though I do not try to drag them, still the event fires. I want to call some other function on click of item.And drag event should be fired only when I drag item. So how to separate out drag event and click event here.

```
function onDragDrop(dragHandler, dropHandler) {
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag();

drag.on("drag", dragHandler)
.on("dragend", dropHandler);
return drag;
}

  var d = [{ x: 20, y: 20 }];

    var g = d3.select("body").select("svg").data(d).append("g").attr("transform", function (d) { return        "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
     .call(onDragDrop(dragmove, dropHandler));

g.append("rect")
.attr("width", 40)
.attr("height", 40)
.attr("stroke", "red")
.attr("fill","transparent")
.attr("x", "20" )
.attr("y", "20")

g.append("text")
.text("Any Text")
.attr("x", "20" )
.attr("y", "20")

function dropHandler(d) {
    alert('dropped');
}

function dragmove(d) {
  alert('dragged');
  d.x += d3.event.dx;
  d.y += d3.event.dy;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
 }
```

Comment: same problem happened with me..

Answer (score 2):

### EDIT 3

This is in response to your alternate answer post.  The fiddle you posted there does not accurately reflect the solution I was trying to describe.  I updated it.  The fiddle below should be an example of the correct way to differentiate click and "true" dragend events.  Note that we are not using a "click" handler.

http://jsfiddle.net/V92CF/

### EDIT 2

Ok, I posted this question on the d3 google group and got an answer from Jason Davies.  The behavior we're seeing is the intended behavior, it's not a bug.  A "click" is simply considered a trival (0 pixels moved) drag, but it is still a drag.  Mike, the creator of d3, explains the reasoning here:

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/368

Hence the correct solution to your problem is the one I described as a hack before: You need to detect if a movement has actually been made inside your dragend handler, and then only trigger your logic if it has.

### EDIT

Please note my original answer below is wrong.  I had misunderstood the problem.  The comments below and my edit to the OP should clarify

### Original Post Below

The only problem here is using `alert`.  I changed all the `alert`s to `console.log`s and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/TrWw3/

I think it's getting confused with the alerts because as soon as you start dragging, it fires the alert box, which requires you to close it.  But then by the time you've closed it the mouse has jumped, and something about the process is messing things up.

Anyway, console.log with chrome or firefox js console open will fix you up nice.

Comment: i have checked console log,'dragend' event still fires on cliking on the item. if i did not start drag, why should dragend fires?

Comment: Ah I see, I'm sorry I misunderstood your problem.  This does look like a bug to me.  Of course, you can manually check the dx and dy values in your handler and ignore the event if they haven't changed, but that is a nasty hack.  Anyway, let me know if you want to edit your original question to use the fiddle with console.log insteads, and then I will I delete this answer if you want.

Comment: As another suggestion, I would edit your title to be "Possible d3 Bug: dragend fires without any drag event".

Comment: Also, I created a much shorter fiddle to demo this bug: http://jsfiddle.net/epMdE/  There is no drag behavior at all in this one, just dragend, and you can see clearly that clicking the element fires the dragend event.

Comment: Actually it seems like a bug.I also can handle it manually but i dont want to even fire 'dragend' event without dragging element. So you can take every possible step to fix it. Thanks for your concern !!

Comment: So, if i want to add 'click' event handler on same element, then i have to fire 'dragend' event first. Looks very illogical. Have u any idea to do this ? 'click' event should fire independently without getting any influence by drag behavior. Is'nt it ?

Comment: Write your click handler as you normally would.  Then inside dragend write an if statment which branches on whether there was actual movement (no movement == ordinary click).  if (no movement) call click handler, else call dragend code.

Comment: Its an alternate, and i could do that even before asking this question here.I think i didnt get my answer. that is why i am not mark your answer accepted. Hope in future it will get fixed

Comment: It's the answer.  This is the officially correct way to do it, and it seems highly unlikely to change in the future.  Read the comments in the link I posted in my second edit.  EDIT: Actually I just saw your latest fiddle, and I think you misunderstood what I meant.  I will make changes and repost and example

Answer (score 1):

> **As i did'nt get expected answer, so i am giving an alternate to acheive this.** Hope somebody has some answer for it. and thanks again @jonah. if you find any update in this regard just let me know. Here is [Alternate way](http://jsfiddle.net/epMdE/3/) to do this.

```
  var d = [{ x: 20, y: 20 }];
  var flag = false;

  var g = d3.select("svg").data(d).append("rect")
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 40)
    .attr("stroke", "red")
    .attr("fill","transparent")
    .attr("x", "20" )
    .attr("y", "20")
    .on("click", function(){ console.log('clicked');})
   .call(d3.behavior.drag().on("drag", dragHandler).on("dragend", dropHandler))

 function dropHandler(d) {
       if(flag){
            console.log('dropped');
            flag = false;
        }}

 function dragHandler(d) {
        flag = true;
        console.log('dragged');
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")");
    }
```

Comment: your Alternate fiddle link is identical with the code in your answer, I think that this is not alternative way than.